# Firefox won't work. Locale not supported by C library

Tags: drivers, firefox, python, c, locale

I just got a server running with ubuntu on it for the first time, I connect with ssh. I am a mac user, learning ubuntu. The idea is to automate some tasks on the server. One of these tasks involves doing some tests with selenium through python. I need to get firefox to work in order to use the driver. I always get this error however:

```
root@gogokino:~# firefox "http://www.google.com/" &
root@gogokino:~# 
(process:32286): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Error: no display specified
[1]+  Exit 1                  firefox "http://www.google.com/"
```

I get a very similar error when I try to run selenium from python.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 61, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 100, in _wait_until_connectable
    self._get_firefox_output())
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: "The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. The output was: \n(process:32301): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not     supported by C library.\n\tUsing the fallback 'C' locale.\nError: no display specified\n"
```

So there seems to be something wrong, something about there not being a C library and something about a locale. I thought C was standard in ubuntu? Is there a quick way to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you install Firefox on a fresh server install? Firefox needs a display set to run and default server installs don't have one. Try running `EXPORT DISPLAY=:0` before running firefox.

Comment: Bit of a noob here. `root@server:~# EXPORT DISPLAY=:0` gives 
`-bash: EXPORT: command not found`

Comment: Hmm. You probably need a display server installed then (the server doesn't come with one, and firefox needs one). I'm working on the C library problem too. On my server I used `sudo apt-get install lxde` for a display server.

Comment: didnt help. im now trying to see if i can get it to work via a vnc.

Comment: After installing a display server, what is the error message now? Did you try exporting the display afterwards?

Comment: i didnt get an error installing the `xlde` but i get the same command not found. im new to ubuntu, what do you mean with exporting the display?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, it should be `export DISPLAY=:0` not `EXPORT DISPLAY=:0` my bad.. You will probably get the same locale error, but not the "display not set" one. Let's tackle one error at a time ;)